# como usar "SET ARITHABORT ON" no vb6

Tags: sql, visual-basic-6

Boa tarde Pessoal,

Precisei usar alguns comando para concatenar alguns registros em uma consulta...

Até ai tudo bem, fiz dessa forma e funcionou:

```
SET ARITHABORT ON; 

SELECT COALESCE((SELECT CAST(FABRICANTE AS VARCHAR(10)) + '/' + CAST(MODELO AS VARCHAR(10)) + '/'  + CAST(ANO AS VARCHAR(10))  AS [text()] FROM OS_recapadora AS O WHERE O.COD_OS = C.COD_OS ORDER BY COD_OS FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), '') AS Produtos
FROM  OS_recapadora  AS C GROUP BY COD_OS;
```

No SQL Server consigo executar normalmente...

Porem, porem preciso usar isso no VB6.... nunca usei o comando "SET ARITHABORT ON" no vb6..
então quando digito no vb6 "SET ARITHABORT ON" fica vermelho como se fosse um comando errado.

Comment: Olá WEBIER. Esse comando é de SQLServer e não de VB6, e não esta claro aonde ele esta ficando em vermelho, se for no editor de textos, isso nada tem haver com a execução, tem coisas que alguns highlight não reconhecem, mas não sei se é no editor que você se refere, a pergunta não esta clara.

Comment: Ela ficou vermelho no vb6.... usei no sql server e rodou normal... agora no vb6 nao aceitou... como usaria o SET ARITHABORT ON no vb6 direto no code line

Comment: Olá, como eu já disse, isso não é comando de VB6 e ficar vermelho não faz sentido, unico lugar que ficaria vermelho é em um editor de texto, o que nada tem haver com execução do código, simplesmente o que você diz não faz sentido, provavelmente você está confundindo algo ou não entendeu o básico de como ocorre a execução.

Comment: Amigo, justamente isso que quero saber... preciso setar o "ARITHABORT " como "ON" dentro do Select no VB6.... pois preciso fazer uma consulta onde preciso que ele esteja ON... a consulta via T-SQL funciona normal(SET ARITHABORT ON)... porem preciso usar essa consulta no VB6

Comment: Ok, mas dentro do VB6 sem mostrar o código não temos como entender o que foi feito e se é de fato erro de sintaxe ou se é simplesmente no seu editor de texto que aparece em vermelho, sua pergunta carece de diversos detalhes. Você tem que se por no lugar das pessoas que vão tentar lhe ajudar e fornecer os detalhes no corpo da pergunta, no momento use o link [edit] e explique exatamente como esta fazendo o passo a passo. Obrigado por compreender.